# Is a set Lebesgue-Stiltjes measurable if and only if it is Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Let $f$ be a real-valued monotone-increasing function, $\kappa$ a sequential covering class of $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of the empty set $\emptyset$ and the open intervals $I_{a,b}=(a,b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are real valued, and we define the set function:

$$
\lambda(I_{a,b}) = f(b) - f(a),
$$
then the Lebesgue-Stiltjes outer measure induced by $f$ is given by:

$$
\mu^*_f(A) = \inf\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda(E_n): E_n \in \kappa, A \subset \cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\},
$$

where $A$ is an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}$. If $f(x)=x$ we get the Lebesgue outer measure. My question is if a set is Lebesgue-Stiltjes (outer) measurable if and only if it is Lebesgue measurable? I considered the definition of measurable sets, where:

$$
\mu^*_f(A) \geq \mu^*_f(A\cap E) + \mu^*_f(A -E),
$$

implies that subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable given that $A$ is any subset of $\mathbb{R}$. I tried assuming e.g. that $f(x) \geq x$ i which case  we would have that

$\mu^*_f(A) \geq \mu^*(A) \geq \mu^*(A\cap E) + \mu^*(A -E)$

but got stuck and couldn't come up with a good argument, especially not for the general case.

Comment: We'll definitely need stronger assumptions on $f$ if we want this: $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is not going to produce the same measurable sets as the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: That's a good point. If we assumed that $f(x)=0$ then $\mu^*_f(A) \geq \mu^*_f(A\cap E) + \mu^*_f(A -E)$ would hold for every set E i.e. all sets would be measurable. So it seems like the Lebesgue measurable sets would be a subset of the Lebesgue-Stiltjes measurable sets, at least for for some $f$. Could it be the case that for a given $f$ as set is Lebasgue measurable but not Lebesgue-Stiltjes measurable?